# Naming a Window in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am looking for a way or a third party software for changing the title of the open window.

For example i have three project open on different Visual Studio instances and all of them has the window titles as their IP adresses like 199.111.21.31... and so on.

What i want to do is edit the name of the windows like 199.111.21.31 - My Project 1, 199.112.22.32 - My Project 2... etc.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using a VBA macro stored in the `EvironmentEvents` macro section.

You may see various formulations of such a macro in the Stack Overflow post
of
[Display solution/file path in Visual Studio IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505/display-solution-file-path-in-visual-studio-ide),
which you may need to modify for getting the title in your format.

There exist also free add-ons that can modify the title. Some are:

- [Customize Visual Studio Window Title](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mayerwin.RenameVisualStudioWindowTitle)
- [Visual Studio Window Title Changer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IstvanPasztor.VisualStudioWindowTitleChanger)